# Upgrading Tails

Tags: upgrade, tails-os

I've been having trouble upgrading Tails. Its been taking a really long time and seems to get stuck or not make any progress. I've also gotten an error message.

Here is the ouput from activating the auto update manually.

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ tails-upgrade-frontend-wrapper
localuser:tails-upgrade-frontend being added to access control list
Prototype mismatch: sub Tails::MirrorPool::assert ($;$) vs none at /usr/share/perl5/Tails/MirrorPool.pm line 28.
Prototype mismatch: sub Tails::IUK::Frontend::assert ($;$) vs none at /usr/share/perl5/Tails/IUK/Frontend.pm line 41.
This version of Tails is outdated, and may have security issues.
_build_boot_block_device: getting liveos_mountpoint
liveos_mountpoint: /lib/live/mount/medium
Entering underlying_block_device (/lib/live/mount/medium)
readlink returned: /dev/sdb1

Leaving underlying_block_device, returning: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1
Upgrade available
<b>You should upgrade to Tails 3.14.2.</b>

For more information about this new version, go to https://tails.boum.org/news/version_3.14.2/

We recommend you close all other applications during the upgrade.
Downloading the upgrade might take a long time, from several minutes to a  few hours.

Download size: 413.42MiB

Do you want to upgrade now?: Upgrade now / Upgrade later

** (zenity:19669): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Downloading the upgrade to Tails 3.14.2...

** (zenity:19694): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

I don't know whether I should be concerned about the WARNING it gave me or the Gtk-Message.

Comment: Open a terminal and run `watch cat /proc/meminfo` while being bored. Watch the dirty buffers and the writeback. Update takes a while.